# How to get all fields from ArcGIS REST API?

Tags: sql, rest, arcgis

I'm looking to obtain all of the available fields from the ArcGIS REST API.  Here is the query link:  https://services1.arcgis.com/zdB7qR0BtYrg0Xpl/ArcGIS/rest/services/ODC_CRIME_OFFENSES_P/FeatureServer/225/query

There are some ObjectID fields that I'd like to see.

Which is leaving out fields like:
DISTRICT_ID, NEIGHBORHOOD_ID and IS_CRIME

Does anyone know how to craft a query that would return all fields?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Set `outFields` to `*`

You should really check out [Esri's documentation on their REST endpoints](https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/services-reference/query-feature-service-layer-.htm) as this is pretty commonly known. Next time do a bit of research before posting :)

Comment: outFields != Fields in the documentation.  Perhaps the documentation could be a bit more clear.

Comment: What do you mean? There is no `fields` parameter in the documentation for the `/query` endpoint, there is only `outFields`